# Getting the std deviation of multiple pictures using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get the standard  deviationof multiple pictures using, OpenCV, here what I've done :

#include 
   #include 
   #include

```
 using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

 int main(){
cv::Mat frame,frame32f;
char filename[40];
cv::Mat mean;
const int count =134;
const int width  = 1920;
const int height = 1080;
cv::Mat resultframe = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat deviationframe = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
for(int i = 1 ; i<= count; i++){
//int i = 3;
sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",i);
frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3 );
resultframe +=frame32f;
frame.release();
}
resultframe *= (1.0/count);
for(int j =1; j<count; j++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",j);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    temp =(frame32f - resultframe);
    deviationframe+= temp.mul(temp);

    //temp.release();
}
imshow("devi",deviationframe);  // works
deviationframe *= 1.0/(count -1);
imshow("devi2",deviationframe); // works
cv::sqrt(deviationframe,deviationframe);
resultframe *= 1.0/255.0;
imshow("devi3",deviationframe);// works
deviationframe *= 1.0/255.0;

imshow("mean ",resultframe);
imshow("deviation frame ",deviationframe);// BLACK FRAME !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

when I see what I get the resultframe"mean value " is correct but the std deviation is just wrong.  any idea what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accumulating the result of **difference squared images** to calculate the standard deviation. The result of your current code is that only the last image is squared and divided by total number of images. All the previous calculations have no effect.

Also, division by `255` is only for **visualization** of the image, not for actual calculations. You are dividing by 255 before calculating the standard deviation which makes your results incorrect.

Modify your code as follows:

```
.
.
.
resultframe *= (1.0/count);
cv::Mat deviationResult = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);

for(int j =1; j< count; j++)
{
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",j);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    deviationframe =(frame32f - resultframe);
    deviationResult += deviationframe.mul(deviationframe);
}
resultframe *= (1.0/255.0);
deviationResult = deviationResult /(count -1 );
cv::sqrt(deviationResult ,deviationResult );
deviationResult *= (1.0/255.0);
imshow("mean ",resultframe);
imshow("deviation frame ",deviationResult);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Comment: @ sgar91 thanks for your answer it make sense but it didn't change the result that I get

Comment: @Engine Oh! I got it. You are not accumulating the **difference squared images**. The current code is just overwriting the previous values when it reaches `deviationframe =(frame32f - resultframe);`. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks again for your help, you're that was one of THE reasons, but now when I devid the deviationframe by 255  I get black frame  I edit my question

Comment: I got it know  I had  to devid it befor running sqrt() on it  or to devid it only by 15,96....  which is the sqrt() of 255

Answer (score 0):

after @sgar91's help here's the final code I hope it helps anybody

```
 #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

 int main(){
cv::Mat frame,frame32f;
char filename[40];
cv::Mat mean;
const int count =134;
const int width  = 1920;
const int height = 1080;
cv::Mat resultframe = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat deviationframe = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat ::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
for(int i = 1 ; i<= count; i++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",i);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3 );
    resultframe +=frame32f;
    frame.release();
}
resultframe *= (1.0/count);
for(int j =1; j<count; j++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",j);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    temp =(frame32f - resultframe);
    deviationframe+= temp.mul(temp);

    //temp.release();
}
deviationframe *= 1.0/(count -1);

deviationframe= deviationframe/255;
cv::sqrt(deviationframe,deviationframe);
resultframe *= 1.0/255.0;
imshow("mean ",resultframe);
imshow("deviation frame ",deviationframe);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
 }
```